# Print to GUI text fields?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm trying to create a GUI Lottery program in Java. The actual code for the Lottery program works pretty well and I have created the GUI as well. The problem is that I can not get the program to run when the "Go" button is pressed and the information is not displayed in the corresponding GUI text fields.

Here is the basic Lotto code with out the GUI involved at all:

```
    package slots;

    import java.util.*;

public class Slots {
static int displaynum[] = new int[5];
static int compnum[] = new int[5];
static int counter=0;
static int matchFound=0;
static int nummatch[] = new int[6];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int z=0; z<5;z++) {
        Random i = new Random();
      //Change 10 to 60
        compnum[z]=i.nextInt((10 - 1) + 1) + 1;
    }
    System.out.println(" " + compnum[0] +"  " + compnum[1] +"  " + compnum[2] +"  " + compnum[3] +"  " + compnum[4]);

    while(nummatch[5]==0) {
        nextGo();
        matchFound=0;
        if(compnum[0]==displaynum[0]) {
            matchFound++;
        }
        if (compnum[1]==displaynum[1]){
            matchFound++;
        }
        if (compnum[2]==displaynum[2]){
            matchFound++;
        } 
        if (compnum[3]==displaynum[3]){
            matchFound++;
        }
        if (compnum[4]==displaynum[4]){
            matchFound++;
        }
        nummatch[matchFound]++;
    }
    System.out.println("  Zero Matches=" + nummatch[0] + "   One Matches=" + nummatch[1] +"   Two Matches=" +  nummatch[2]+ "   Three Matches=" + nummatch[3]+ "   Four Matches=" + nummatch[4]+ "   Total Draws=" + counter);

}


static void nextGo() {
    for(int x=0;x<5;x++) {
        Random i = new Random();
        //Change 10 to 60
        displaynum[x]=i.nextInt((10 - 1) + 1) + 1;
    }
    counter++;

    System.out.println("  " + displaynum[0] +"  " + displaynum[1] +"  " + displaynum[2] +"  " + displaynum[3] +"  " + displaynum[4]);
}
 }
```

So the above code shows each lotto drawing and displays the different matches properly. But I'm having trouble getting those same outputs to display in the GUI text fields.

Here is my attempt at combining the above code and the GUI:

```
    package slots;

    import java.awt.*; 
    import java.awt.event.*; 
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.*;

  public class LottoGUI extends Frame implements ActionListener {

private static TextField tfOne;
private static TextField tfTwo;
private static TextField tfThree;
private static TextField tfFour;
private static TextField tfFive;
private Label lblmnZero;
private static TextField mnZero;
private Label lblmnOne;
private static TextField mnOne;
private Label lblmnTwo;
private static TextField mnTwo;
private Label lblmnThree;
private static TextField mnThree;
private Label lblmnFour;
private static TextField mnFour;
private Label lbltfDraws;
private static TextField tfDraws;
private Button btnGo;
private Button btnClose;

public LottoGUI() {
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

      tfOne = new TextField("", 2);
      tfOne.setEditable(false);
      add(tfOne);
      tfTwo = new TextField("", 2);
      tfTwo.setEditable(false);
      add(tfTwo);
      tfThree = new TextField("", 2);
      tfThree.setEditable(false);
      add(tfThree);
      tfFour = new TextField("", 2);
      tfFour.setEditable(false);
      add(tfFour);
      tfFive = new TextField("", 2);
      tfFive.setEditable(false);
      add(tfFive);

      lblmnZero = new Label("Zero Matches:");
      add(lblmnZero);
      mnZero = new TextField("");
      mnZero.setEditable(false);
      add(mnZero);
      lblmnOne = new Label("One Matches:");
      add(lblmnOne);
      mnOne = new TextField("");
      mnOne.setEditable(false);
      add(mnOne);
      lblmnTwo = new Label("Two Matches:");
      add(lblmnTwo);
      mnTwo = new TextField("");
      mnTwo.setEditable(false);
      add(mnTwo);
      lblmnThree = new Label("Three Matches:");
      add(lblmnThree);
      mnThree = new TextField("");
      mnThree.setEditable(false);
      add(mnThree);
      lblmnFour = new Label("Four Matches:");
      add(lblmnFour);
      mnFour = new TextField("");
      mnFour.setEditable(false);
      add(mnFour);
      lbltfDraws = new Label("Total Draws:");
      add(lbltfDraws);
      tfDraws = new TextField("");
      tfDraws.setEditable(false);
      add(tfDraws);

      btnGo = new Button("GO");
      add(btnGo);
      btnClose = new Button("CLOSE");
      add(btnClose);

      btnGo.addActionListener(this);
      btnClose.addActionListener(this);

      setTitle("Lotto");
        setSize(1000, 100);
        setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new LottoGUI();

}

public static class Slots {
    static int displaynum[] = new int[5];
    static int compnum[] = new int[5];
    static int counter=0;
    static int matchFound=0;
    static int nummatch[] = new int[6];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int z=0; z<5;z++) {
            Random i = new Random();
          //Change 10 to 60
            compnum[z]=i.nextInt((10 - 1) + 1) + 1;
        }
        //System.out.println(" " + compnum[0] +"  " + compnum[1] +"  " + compnum[2] +"  " + compnum[3] +"  " + compnum[4]);
        Object[] obcm0 = {compnum[0]};
        mnZero.setText(Arrays.toString(obcm0));
        Object[] obcm1 = {compnum[1]};
        mnOne.setText(Arrays.toString(obcm1));
        Object[] obcm2 = {compnum[2]};
        mnTwo.setText(Arrays.toString(obcm2));
        Object[] obcm3 = {compnum[3]};
        mnThree.setText(Arrays.toString(obcm3));
        Object[] obcm4 = {compnum[4]};
        mnFour.setText(Arrays.toString(obcm4));

        while(nummatch[5]==0) {
            nextGo();
            matchFound=0;
            if(compnum[0]==displaynum[0]) {
                matchFound++;
            }
            if (compnum[1]==displaynum[1]){
                matchFound++;
            }
            if (compnum[2]==displaynum[2]){
                matchFound++;
            } 
            if (compnum[3]==displaynum[3]){
                matchFound++;
            }
            if (compnum[4]==displaynum[4]){
                matchFound++;
            }
            nummatch[matchFound]++;
        }
        //System.out.println("  Zero Matches=" + nummatch[0] + "   One Matches=" + nummatch[1] +"   Two Matches=" +  nummatch[2]+ "   Three Matches=" + nummatch[3]+ "   Four Matches=" + nummatch[4]+ "   Total Draws=" + counter);
        Object[] obnm0 = {nummatch[0]};
        mnZero.setText(Arrays.toString(obnm0));
        Object[] obnm1 = {nummatch[1]};
        mnOne.setText(Arrays.toString(obnm1));
        Object[] obnm2 = {nummatch[2]};
        mnTwo.setText(Arrays.toString(obnm2));
        Object[] obnm3 = {nummatch[3]};
        mnThree.setText(Arrays.toString(obnm3));
        Object[] obnm4 = {nummatch[4]};
        mnFour.setText(Arrays.toString(obnm4));
        Object[] obcn = {counter};
        tfDraws.setText(Arrays.toString(obcn));
    }


    static void nextGo() {
        for(int x=0;x<5;x++) {
            Random i = new Random();
            //Change 10 to 60
            displaynum[x]=i.nextInt((10 - 1) + 1) + 1;
        }
        counter++;

        //System.out.println("  " + displaynum[0] +"  " + displaynum[1] +"  " + displaynum[2] +"  " + displaynum[3] +"  " + displaynum[4]);
        Object[] obdn0 = {displaynum[0]};
        tfOne.setText(Arrays.toString(obdn0));
        Object[] obdn1 = {displaynum[1]};
        tfTwo.setText(Arrays.toString(obdn1));
        Object[] obdn2 = {displaynum[2]};
        tfThree.setText(Arrays.toString(obdn2));
        Object[] obdn3 = {displaynum[3]};
        tfFour.setText(Arrays.toString(obdn3));
        Object[] obdn4 = {displaynum[4]};
        tfFive.setText(Arrays.toString(obdn4));
    }
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String str = e.getActionCommand();

     if(str.equals("GO"))
        new Slots();

     else if (str.equals("CLOSE"))
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

Nothing happens when I click the "GO" button. Maybe I'm placing the print commands in the wrong section of the code or I'm not doing something else incorrectly? I'd really appreciate any guidance with this.

This is also my first posting to this site so if I've messed up anything please let me know. I've been searching for help and can't find much that pertains to my issue. Thank you!

Comment: You look to be trying to merge a static linear console program with an event driven GUI, and that never works. For one, your while loop is blocking your Swing event thread, which risks making the GUI non-functioning. You need to re-write your program logic so that it works in an event driven way. Create true objects, and make almost all of your fields and methods non-static.

Answer (score 2):

You look to be trying to merge a static linear console program with an event driven GUI, and that never works. For one, your while loop is blocking your Swing event thread, which risks making the GUI non-functioning. You need to re-write your program logic so that it works in an event driven way. Create true objects, and make almost all of your fields and methods non-static.

For example, I'd make most all my fields, except for constants, non-static. I'd make most of my fields private and make only the methods that need to be called by other classes public. I'd pass references to objects that need to call the methods of the original object. For instance, here is a small program that does sort of what you're trying to do (but not exactly as that would be cheating) and can give the idea of what I'm getting at:

```
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SimpleGui extends JPanel {
   private static final int TEXT_FIELD_COLUMNS = 3;
   private JTextField[] textFields = new JTextField[SimpleModel.VALUES_COUNT];
   private JButton goButton = new JButton(new GoAction("Go", KeyEvent.VK_G));
   private JButton exitButton = new JButton(new ExitAction("Exit",
         KeyEvent.VK_X));
   private SimpleModel simpleModel = new SimpleModel(this);

   public SimpleGui() {
      for (int i = 0; i < textFields.length; i++) {
         textFields[i] = new JTextField(TEXT_FIELD_COLUMNS);
         textFields[i].setEditable(false);
         textFields[i].setFocusable(false);
         add(textFields[i]);
      }
      add(goButton);
      add(exitButton);
   }

   public void setTextFieldText(int index, String text) {
      if (index < 0 || index >= textFields.length) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("index: " + index);
      } else {
         textFields[index].setText(text);
      }
   }

   private class GoAction extends AbstractAction {
      public GoAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
         super(name);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         simpleModel.go();
      }
   }

   private class ExitAction extends AbstractAction {
      public ExitAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
         super(name);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         JButton btn = (JButton) e.getSource();
         Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(btn);
         win.dispose();
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleGui");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new SimpleGui());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class SimpleModel {
   public static final int MAX_VALUE = 100;
   public static final int VALUES_COUNT = 4;
   private Random random = new Random();
   private SimpleGui simpleGui;
   private int[] values = new int[VALUES_COUNT];

   public SimpleModel(SimpleGui simpleGui) {
      this.simpleGui = simpleGui;
   }

   public void go() {
      for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
         values[i] = random.nextInt(MAX_VALUE) + 1;
         simpleGui.setTextFieldText(i, String.valueOf(values[i]));
      }

      // TODO: use the values array here
   }
}
```

It passes a reference from the SimpleGui class to the SimpleModel's class by passing `this` into the model's constructor:

```
private SimpleModel simpleModel = new SimpleModel(this);
```

The model takes this reference and uses it to set the GUI field:

```
class SimpleModel {
   //....

   private SimpleGui simpleGui;

   // ...

   public SimpleModel(SimpleGui simpleGui) {
      this.simpleGui = simpleGui;
   }
```

And then the model's go method calls a public method of the GUI to set the text field text:

```
public void go() {
  for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
     values[i] = random.nextInt(MAX_VALUE) + 1;
     simpleGui.setTextFieldText(i, String.valueOf(values[i]));
  }

  // TODO: use the values array here
}
```

Note that if this were true MVC, model-view-control, the model would not call the GUI's methods at all, but rather would notify listeners of change in state, but that's for a later discussion.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the information! I will continue to work on this and use the above code as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to make a call to nextGo()

Replace

```
if(str.equals("GO"))
        new Slots();
```

with

```
if(str.equals("GO"))
        new Slots().nextGo();
```

This should solve the issue.

**Update 1:**

Please remove static from nextGo() are you sure your code is getting compiled when you access a non static object from a static method?

Comment: Thank you! That did get some of the numbers to display in the GUI but I still need to work on it some more.